# SQLAlchemy: mirror a non-primary column from another table

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I want to have a table, `Goals`, which is in a one-to-many relationship with another table, `Hints`, meaning one hint can be for many goals, but each goal has one hint. Now I want `Goals` to reflect two of the columns in `Hints`. `Hints` has columns `id` (primary) and `penalty` (non-unique) and I want `Goals` to have columns `hint_id` and `hint_penalty` which mirror those of the linked hint. I understand how the `id` can be mirrored, since it's the primary key in `Hint` and using a relationship nicely updates it on flush, but `penalty` doesn't seem to be propagated.

Here is what I mean:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref


Base = declarative_base()


class Hint(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hint'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    penalty = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

class Goal(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'goal'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hint_penalty = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('hint.penalty'))
    hint_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hint.id'))
    hint = relationship(
        # this leaves hint_penalty blank
        Hint, foreign_keys=[hint_id],
        # this raises sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError
        #  Hint, foreign_keys=[hint_id, hint_penalty],
        backref=backref('goals', uselist=True))


engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

g1 = Goal()
h1 = Hint(penalty=1, goals=[g1])
h2 = Hint(penalty=1)
g2 = Goal(hint=h2)

session.add(h1)
session.add(h2)
session.commit()

print((
    'g1.hint_id = {hid1}\n'
    'g1.hint_penalty = {hp1}\n'
    'g2.hint_id = {hid2}\n'
    'g2.hint_penalty = {hp2}\n'
).format(
    hid1=g1.hint_id,
    hp1=g1.hint_penalty,
    hid2=g2.hint_id,
    hp2=g2.hint_penalty))
```

Whichever order I create the goal and hint, `goal.hint_penalty` is always `None`:

```
g1.hint_id = 1
g1.hint_penalty = None
g2.hint_id = 2
g2.hint_penalty = None
```

How can I propagate `hint.penalty` to `goal.hint_penalty` upon flush?

I know of course I can access this via `goal.hint.penalty`, but for my situation this is not desirable.

Comment: Why is it not desirable?

Comment: Too long to explain all the details of the project, but an instance of `Goal` would be converted to a dictionary and it's necessary that the `hint` attribute is omitted during that conversion. It'd be too much code changes and ugly code in order to omit leave `goal.hint` but omit all columns except `goal.hint.penalty`.

Comment: If all you need is an instance level attribute that mirrors the value, have you considered using a `@property`?

Comment: @IljaEverilä wow, I hadn't thought of that! Tried it and works. Brilliant solution, thanks :) If you post an answer with it I can accept it.

Comment: @IljaEverilä ... except the `@property` doesn't show up in the object's `__dict__` or in `inspect(obj).attrs`. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an appropriate `primaryjoin` to the relationship did the job:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref


Base = declarative_base()


class Hint(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hint'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    penalty = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

class Goal(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'goal'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hint_penalty = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('hint.penalty'))
    hint_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hint.id'))
    hint = relationship(
        Hint,
        primaryjoin="and_(Hint.penalty == foreign(Goal.hint_penalty), "
                    "Hint.id == foreign(Goal.hint_id))",
        backref=backref('goals', uselist=True))
```

Comment: Worth a note that this denormalization will not always mirror changes to `hint.penalty` and so can lead to anomalies.

Comment: @IljaEverilä can you give examples of such cases?